# Detect / Confirm open QInputDialog

Tags: python, qt, modal-dialog, pyqt

In a test environment, that does GUI testing an application, there occurs the situation (depends on the current configuration which is being tested), that the user is prompted for a selection via a `QInputDialog`.

The problem is, that this holds the  running test, until one manually clicks the OK button (no further action necessary). However, I do not know how to detect this dialog programatically. Actually I'm not sure, whether is is possible, since the main loop will remain in the function where the dialog is opened, until it gets user confirmation.

dialog

```
measure, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getItem(self.centralWidget, \
              "Select the measure to apply", "Measure:", items, 0, False)
```

the function for testing

```
print('--- Button click')

# Invokes some GUI action that in some cases includes a user input prompt via 
# the QInputDialog above
self.p.TabValid.buttonRun.click() 

# I tried these ones, but the program won't reach here
# because it is stuck as soon as the dialog opens
print('Widget with focus:', self.app.activeModalWidget())
print('Widget with focus:', self.app.focusWidget())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as an event loop is running, your code will always be in control. Simply execute some code on a periodic timer that checks if the active widget is an `QInputDialog`, and forcibly accept that input. Use `qApp.activeWindow` or `qApp.activeModalWidget`.

Comment: I used `QTimer.singleShot` to call a function, checking for the `activeWindow()` *after* `buttonRun.click()`. `QInputDialog.accept()` did the rest. Good hint.